# Is it possible to return only one field from foreign collection after $lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to return only a specific field from the foreign collection using `$lookup` without using additional `$project` pipeline in `MongoDB`?

```
db.orders.aggregate([
       {
         $lookup:
           {
             from: "inventory",
             localField: "item",
             foreignField: "sku",
             as: "inventory_docs"
           }
      }
    ])
```

Result

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "item" : "almonds",
   "price" : 12,
   "quantity" : 2,
   "inventory_docs" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "sku" : "almonds", "description" : "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
   ]
}
```

Above query returning all fields of `inventory` collection but I need only `description` field.

Comment: You can use $lookup variant which takes the pipeline and use $project. In any case you have to use $project to limit fields.

Comment: I am using mongo version 3.4 but $lookup with the pipeline is supported from 3.6 and later.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to use project stage. If you are worried about listing all the fields  you can use $addFields stage and only list the description field. Something like `{$addFields:{inventory_docs:"$inventory_docs.description"}}`. This is the best you can do in 3.4